# How to carbonate a drink?

Tags: drinks, carbonation

How do I carbonate a drink that originally isn't carbonated without altering its taste or the process taking more than a few hours? I've seen some methods that use yeast, but that requires about two days and the taste changes, so that won't do.

Comment: What country are you in? In some countries, "soda flasks" are a dime a dozen, and when you get a refilled CO2 cartridge, it's apparent that the cartridge has been around longer than you have. In other countries, you have to buy a fancy-schmancy machine with a fancy-schmancy brand name, because nobody else makes anything of the sort.

Comment: I'm in Russia, and it's likely that I'll have to make both the machine and the flask by myself :p

Comment: Russia? Really? Eastern bloc countries all had thriving soda cartridge exchanges back in the day; are you sure you can't find a soda flask in the dusty back corner of your local hardware/household goods store?

Comment: I would advise against making the machine yourself. There are safety issues involved, a malfunctioning machine can explode with enough force to take off your fingers. Carbonating machines were available in Eastern Europe even before the wall fell, so you will probably be able to buy one today too.

Comment: What I've heard from my grandparents, the devices from back in the days caused way too many serious injuries, and two people I know in the neighborhood lost an eye to that stuff. I'm sure if I look for them, I'll find these devices, but I'd like to learn some less dangerous methods.

Comment: Amazon doesn't sell SodaStream machines in Russia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wilds of Russia?
If you have dry ice, just adding pieces of it (chopped small) to your drink will work to some extent. Here's a vid: [How To Make Soda With Dry Ice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IK63uYVFZE) Be aware that not all dry ice is food grade.
If no dry ice, you can get by with sodium bicarbonate (baking soda) and vinegar (acetic acid), or some other acid.
Just mix the two chemicals, and bubble the resulting gas through your drink.
Here's an Instructable, w video: [Carbonating: The Cheap and Easy Way](http://www.instructables.com/id/Carbonating%3a-The-Cheap-and-Easy-Way/). It'd be easy to improve on the kid's method, for example by adding a [bubbler stone](https://www.google.com/search?q=bubbler%20stone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), but the general principles are sound.
Either method will cause some change in your liquid's taste, as you're lowering the pH by generating carbonic acid, but that's true of *any* carbonation scheme.

Answer (score 4):

### How to do it - practical advice

You need a machine for carbonation. There are different brands. You buy cartridges with gas for them, put the bottle with the drink in the machine with the loaded cartridge, and press a button a few times. The drink is then carbonated.

I there are also combined whippers/carbonators which can alternatively take a nitrous oxide cartridge to make foams. This is too complicated and unnecessary if all you need are carbonated drinks. If you are like most people out there, you want the simple system which just carbonates.

### Update: Some more words on what forms of carbonation are available

Carbonation is a process in which you get CO2 bubbles dissolved in a liquid. The gas doesn't stay dissolved for a long time, it starts "seeping out" of the liquid, forming tiny bubbles, which rise through the liquid, giving a prickly feeling on your tongue when they reach it.

You can get the gas into the liquid by three general classes of
   methods: add an organism which produces CO2 (biological method), add
   a compound which reacts to produce CO2 (chemical method), or add the
   gas directly (physical method).

- Adding yeast is a **biological method**. Yeast metabolizes parts of
  the drink, and releases CO2 as a byproduct. This needs time for the
  yeast to live enough to produce enough waste gases, and it indeed
  changes the taste, as the yeast eats up some nutrients itself, and
  releases other byproducts beside CO2. These disadvantages are common
  to all biological methods, no matter which kind of microorganism you
  choose.

  You could also use a **chemical method**. It also changes the taste,
  as compounds within the drink are used up in chemical reactions, and
  there are also products beside the CO2, which have a taste of their
  own. A further problem is that you can't get much gas produced that
  way, and what you produce dissipates very quickly. So, it is not
  advisable to carbonate drinks using chemical methods.

  The third way is the **physical method**. You don't produce CO2, but
  add existing CO2 into the drink. Normally, if you just bring a drink
  and CO2 gas together, the gas won't dissolve. What you need to make
  this work is to release CO2 into the liquid under pressure. The
  instrument which does this is a soda-making machine; it gets a
  cartridge of CO2 under pressure. When you push the button, the
  cartridge is opened, and the pressurized gas escapes from the
  cartridge into the drink, where it gets dissolved. This is the
  easiest method of the three, and has no disadvantages beyond the
  investment in a machine and cartridges. There are inexpensive
  machines for home use, so it is what I advise you to use.

Manufacturers sometimes combine machines which can expel CO2 from cartridges with machines which can expel NO from cartridges. Expelling NO is used for whipping foams, e.g. creating whipped cream. The whipped cream spray bottles in the supermarket are a simplified version of such machines, which cannot be reloaded.

While the construction of CO2 expelling machines and NO expelling machines is similar enough that it makes sense to combine them in a single body, the use cases for CO2 use and NO use are very different. If you only want to carbonate, a CO2 machine is sufficient.

Comment: I guess I'm after the simplest form of carbonation, but please do tell of other methods.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. The other thing I mentioned doesn't give you a differnt form of carbonation, it is a machine which can both carbonate drinks and whip cream. I warned you that you probably don't want that, so an overzealous salesman doesn't saddle you with an expensive system which has more functions than you need. These other functions are not for carbonation.

Comment: I have to disagree: I think the simplest form of carbonation is one of those flasks that takes a cartridge. The fact that it can take a cartridge with different gasses shouldn't make any difference. However, rumtscho is right in that if you can find a flask that *only* takes CO2 cartridges, it's likely to be the absolute simplest method possible.

Comment: @marti I find the idea of "carbonation flask" interesting, but haven't seen one. Can you post a link to a description? It sounds like it could be the whole mechanism of the bigger machine contained in a single bottlecap or similar.

Comment: Here's a typical one - the cartridge goes in the part sticking out to the top right. http://p2.vatera.hu/photos/31/04/4bc6_1_big.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers already covered most of what we need to know, but I'm going to add some additional perspective with mine.

All you need to do is get carbonic acid in the water somehow (which can happen when carbon dioxide is being released by such as the biological, chemical, or physical methods outlined in rumtscho's answer). This can be enhanced by pressure. Maintaining pressure (enclosing the container) while some of this is going on can increase the carbonation (but it can also be dangerous and cause explosions, and if you're using dry ice, it can be illegal if it explodes and/or is meant to explode). That's why people burp ferments, or use airlocks on their ferments (so they don't explode). However, the increased pressure should often lead to increased carbonation. If there's no carbonation in a ferment, there probably wasn't enough pressure with the CO2 build-up. But, I digress, as fermentation is a slow process.

Here's a fast and easy chemical method (and while it actually does change the taste a bit, I think in this particular case, the taste is an improvement, which is why I deign to mention it--since I think that's in keeping with the spirit of your question):

1. Take some cold Great Value orange juice. (I've only ever used the calcium fortified kind for this purpose, so far.)
2. Add baking soda (maybe add about a half a teaspoon, or less, for a quart of OJ).
3. Stir thoroughly for thirty seconds to a minute.
4. Enjoy. It's carbonated, and it tastes great. Seriously. See the notes below.

Oranges are already kind of bitter (even if you don't notice it); bitterness of the baking soda isn't noticeable unless you add more baking soda than is required to carbonate it (but even if you add too much, it just tastes like particularly bitter citrus tastes). If you add a desirable amount of baking soda, the orange juice doesn't taste more bitter: It makes it taste creamier instead.

I imagine if you contained the beverage to build up some pressure while you were mixing in the baking soda, then it might carbonate even more. But, it's sufficiently carbonated as is, in my opinion.

You can expect some orange juice to foam a bit after about 45 seconds of stirring. Not all orange juice will foam. Foam isn't necessary for carbonation.

To make club soda (via the same chemical method), you can do this:

Ingredients:

1. Cold water
2. [Citric acid](https://nuts.com/cookingbaking/salts/citric-acid/1lb.html) (ascorbic acid works, too, and it spits more, but I think citric acid makes a tastier soda that feels better on my system); add enough citric acid to make the water resemble restaurant lemonade in taste potency
3. Baking soda (about the same amount as with OJ)

I think it tastes better, and less bitter, than store-bought club soda (and more carbonated than most I've tried). You can make it as carbonated as you want, pretty much, depending on how much citric acid and baking soda you add. Getting the right ratio of citric acid and baking soda is important (if all of it is involved in the reaction, it should be less bitter than if there's some left-over baking soda that didn't react). If it's too bitter, you might try adding more citric acid (or less baking soda next time).

Of course, you could switch out water with pretty much any beverage (but depending on what the beverage is, it might get an unpleasant taste). So, you need to use the right kinds of juices or what-have-you, if you want to avoid the flavor concern. Yes, you could add additional citric acid to orange juice, if you want to get more carbonation.

Citric acid and baking soda produce a fine carbonation (the bubbles are smaller, but they're still there, and they still make the tongue and throat tingle, and promote burping; it doesn't make me burp quite as much as store-bought soda, per amount of carbonation, but it does make me burp, and it does make the tongue/throat tingle just as much).

I've only ever consumed these chemically-created soft drinks directly after creation. I can't say whether they remain carbonated after long periods in the refrigerator (maybe if you put them in a soda bottle with a tight lid).

Keep in mind that baking soda (sodium bicarobate) contains sodium, although it is less sodium than table salt (sodium chloride) contains.

I imagine you could use potassium bicarbonate instead of sodium bicarbonate (but I haven't tried or tasted that).

Anyway, so my answer doesn't work with all beverages, but it is a fast way to make delicious soft drinks out of some beverages.

Note that baking soda is alkaline and will raise the pH of orange juice.